# centering IFrame inside div in centering position screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i want to center iframe inside div in the center of screen how can i make it ,i don't know if missing something to add any one can help me please .i try to add margin :0 auto to #iframe but no worked yet what i need to do it .

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      
    <style>

        
        #div1{
            margin-left:auto; 
            margin-right:auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            width:100%;
            height:1000px;
          
            }


     #iframe{
        width: 60%;
        height: 1000px; 
        background: #FFFFFF;
       
       
    }
 
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
      
           <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#">About us</a>

            </li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#">Contact us</a>

            </li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#">Services</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Address</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div style="width:auto;margin:0 auto;">
        <div id="div1">
            <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="auto" align="middle" frameborder="0" onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0)" src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you know that the `width` of `#iframe` is `60%`, you can set the margins to `20%` to center it.

```css
#div1 {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
#iframe {
  width: 60%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">

    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="drop">
        <a href="#">About us</a>

      </li>
      <li class="drop">
        <a href="#">Contact us</a>

      </li>
      <li class="drop">
        <a href="#">Services</a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Address</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div style="width:auto;margin:0 auto;">
    <div id="div1">
      <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="auto" align="middle" frameborder="0" onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0)" src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that div inside another div, set the outter div width to 100% position relative, and then the inner div position to relative and margins to auto;

```css
#outterDiv {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#innerDiv {
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">

  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">About us</a>

    </li>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>

    </li>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">Services</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Address</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div id="outterDiv">
  <div id="innerDiv">
    <iframe id="iframe" scrolling="auto" align="middle" frameborder="0" onload="window.scrollTo(0, 0)" src="http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx?hid=10000&chid=0&rate=IBE&css=brown" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```